# Not able to move screen from my obj c to my another vc which have home tab bar application

Tags: ios, swift

I have one Objective-C class. An interface manager between my Cocoa class  to my Objective-C class. I am passing value to Swift class where once I end my session with submit button in my Cocoa class. Then from my interface class I am using notification center to go to another VC. But my application has a tab bar. So each time I need to go to home and then it's going to sessionvc. I don't want to show my home VC. I directly want to show my sessionvc.

Here is my code working with coming to home VC and then going to sessionvc:

Update code:

```
   @objc func onOver(notification: NSNotification)
    {
   if let score = notification.object as? NSDictionary
        {
            DispatchQueue.background(delay: 0.1000, completion:{
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Trai", bundle: nil);
                    if let sessionvc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                        "sessionvc") as? sessionvc{

                        if let navController = TopView.topViewController()?.navigationController as? UINavigationController{
                            TopView.topViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(sessionvc, animated: true)
                        }else{
                            TopView.topViewController()?.present(sessionvc, animated: true)

                        }
                }
            }
        })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain your problem better, preferably with screenshots/flow diagrams

Comment: its simple, i want to go my another vc without coming back to my home screen. If i remove my line `elf.showHome()` from my `onSessionOver` method, then its not at all coming to my `sessionvc screen`

Comment: your sessionvc and homevc is in tabbar view controller?

Comment: have you debugged your  control is reaching at this line   let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "TBTrain", bundle: nil);  in onSessionOver selector ?

Comment: @kerry my homevc having tab bar. But my sessionvc dont have tab bar

Comment: @AbuUlHassan No, its reaching this line ` if let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? TBTabBarController{` and full white screen

Comment: then check my answer

Comment: This is also possible you don't have navigation controller in tabbar ? 
in that case you need to present controller instead of push.

Answer (score 0):

You Case actually contains three thing that is TabbrController and may be navigation controller and of course UIViewController, so when posting a notification from a non UIViewController class you will never know on what controller you are so accessing nav controller with 0 index will not solve your problem Try Following  to determine your top controller.

```
//Put this in separate file

import UIKit
class Utility:NSObject{
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }

}
```

And then instead of doing this

```
if let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? TBTabBarController{
                    if let navController: UINavigationController  = controller.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController
                    {
```

**Do this**

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "TBTrain", bundle: nil);
                    if let sessionController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                        "Ssessionvc") as? Ssessionvc{

if let navController = Utility.topViewController()?.navigationController as? UINavigationController{  Utility.topViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(sessionController, animated: true)
                        }
    }
    else{
    Utility.topViewController()?.present(sessionController, animated: true)

}
```

**Note: ** If in case you  don't have any navigation controller in tabbar  in that case you actually need to present controller instead of push

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193515/discussion-on-answer-by-abu-ul-hassan-not-able-to-move-screen-from-my-obj-c-to-m).

Comment: @Abu Ul Hassan  Still i was not able to solve my issues. Can you please help on that.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Sorry for an late replay, I updated my code Its working for first time. Second time, i am getting white blank screen, I added break point, It coming this line `TopView.topViewController()?.present(sessionvc, animated: true)
` and getting white screen from second time onward.

Comment: now that is some logical issue you have to find it by your own.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan  i was not able to find it out, when it adding first time, as top of the current vc, again same process only. Should i needs to remove any vc from top ?

Comment: may be, actually right now i am not in condition of thinking.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan  Still i was not able to find out what is an exact issues. Can you please help on that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395649/getting-white-screen-after-second-time-of-showing-vc-in-the-current-vc